# How to customize OOTB workflow emails

Tags: email, workflow

How can I make simple format-type customizations to ALL OOTB workflow related emails?

I have found that many pre-Sharepoint 2010 posts indicated that OOTB workflow emails are in fact 'alerts', and therefore OOTB workflow emails could be customized using the same technique which is: making a customized version of alerttemplates.xml and even using IAlertNotifyHandler to intercept all alert emails.  However, it seems that OOTB workflow and workflow task emails are not affected by changes to my customalerttemplates.xml file (which I do follow with stsadm updatealerttemplates, iisreset, and timer service restart).

This is what I used as a guide to customize alerts:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx

What am I missing?  Is there a separate template for workflow emails?  Can OOTB workflow emails be customized?

Thanks!

Jeff